# Python and Google Sketchup

Tags: script, python, sketchup

Is there any way of scripting Google Sketchup using Python rather than Ruby? I have had a look at SuPy but unforturnately I'm working with Python 2.6 rather than Python 2.5 which SuPy appears to require.

Comment: Maybe you can make SuPy work: http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/SuPy/